# How can I get my ssh keys and identity into ddev's web container?

Tags: drush, ddev

I have these needs from time to time in the web container:

- ssh to a server from inside the web container
- Use git to a private repository inside the web container
- Use rsync (like `ddev drush rsync`)
- Use `ddev composer` with access to private repositories

So how can I get my keys into the container?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

DDEV supports having your ssh keys in the container without mounting them there, using an ssh-agent inside docker.

You can authenticate and add your keys via `ddev auth ssh`, and they will then be available from every project. This works for ssh from inside the container, private composer repositories, and `drush rsync`.

See https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/basics/cli-usage/#ssh-into-containers for docs.

Comment: could you please highlight the valid response more and seperate it more freom the obsolete response? Was a bit confusing at first...

Comment: Note: `ddev auth ssh` will only add keys in **OpenSSH format**

Comment: Under which path can I find the keys in the web container after running `ddev auth ssh`? If I `ddev ssh` into the container and look in the `~/.ssh` directory, there is only a config file, but no key files.

Comment: The whole idea of `ddev auth ssh` is that the keys don't go into the web container. They're served by an ssh agent running in the ddev-ssh-agent container.

Comment: If you really want the ssh keys inside the container you can do it, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61485062/215713

Comment: The ddev link in the answer is broken . You find it at https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/basics/cli-usage/#ssh-into-containers

Comment: Thanks @batigolix - I fixed the link and added a redirect in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I am having an issue that popped up after updating mac that I simply cannot fix. My yaml files are not ommitting ssh but I get this error, all the time.

ddev-ssh-agent is omitted in your configuration so ssh auth cannot be used

Comment: Please don't post a question as if it were an answer. If you're getting `ddev-ssh-agent is omitted in your configuration so ssh auth cannot be used` that means that you have `omit_containers: [ssh-agent]` in your global configuration - in `~/.ddev/global_config.yaml` - that's the global_config.yaml file in the .ddev folder in your home directory.